# How do I pass a variable into -job on Copy-DbaAgentJob?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, dbatools

I'm trying to query one the source instance and copy across any missing jobs into the destination instance. Everything seems to work except passing the name into -job. Can anyone suggest a fix or point me in the right direction?

```
$dest = "Dest\Instance"
$Source = "Source\Instance"
$MissingJob = Invoke-DbaQuery -SqlInstance $Source -ReadOnly -Query "
use msdb

select name
from dbo.sysjobs
where name COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS not in (select name
from [Dest\Instance].[msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs]
)"

foreach ($Name in $MissingJob){
Copy-DbaAgentJob -Source NCCSQLDEVW2K162\NCCSQL2017DBA01 -Destination $dest 
-Job $Name -SourceSqlCredential $cred -Force 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to reinvent the wheel with the linked server query. dbatools also provides the [`Get-DbaAgentJob`](https://github.com/sqlcollaborative/dbatools/blob/development/functions/Get-DbaAgentJob.ps1) function to enumerate jobs on both agents. As well, the `$Job` parameter accepts an array as input, meaning you don't need the for-loop. Assuming the job name is the keying attribute as in your sample, you could try something like the following.

```
$sourceJobs = Get-DbaAgentJob -SqlInstance '[Source\Instance]'
$destJobs   = Get-DbaAgentJob -SqlInstance '[Dest\Instance]'

$missingJobs = $sourceJobs | Where {
    $_.Name -notin $destJobs.Name
}

Copy-DbaAgentJob `
    -Source '[Source\Instance]' `
    -Destination '[Dest\Instance]' `
    -Job $missingJobs
```

Although strictly speaking, `Copy-DbaAgentJob` already checks for duplicates, so you could slim it down even further by just omitting the `-Job` parameter entirely and just run something like...

```
Copy-DbaAgentJob `
    -Source '[Source\Instance]' `
    -Destination '[Dest\Instance]' `
```

...which will show you which jobs were skipped because they already exist.

[image: powershell session showing Copy-DbaAgentJob output]

Comment: thanks man, it was just my lack experience with powershell and dbtools. So I kind of fudging it. But that works way better thank you so much :-)

Comment:  i recommend the [dbatools slack channel](https://dbatools.io/dbatools-is-now-on-the-sql-server-communitys-slack/) as well for a really helpful positive place to ask questions about the module day-to-day

Comment: Cheers mate i will